# Merge "car-mode" to "car-dock" tag?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

Another "merge-and-synonym" request: [car-mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/car-mode) (x1) should IMHO be merged into [car-dock](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/car-dock) (x9) and made a synonym to it (makes together 10 questions).

Comment: I'm an Android dev specifically in regards to car mode and car docks. They are not equivalent. A Car Dock holds the phone and *may* put the phone into Car Mode due to pin connectors/magnets on the phone/dock. However, you can start Car Mode without a Car Dock. So the two are related, but I don't see a good reason to merge them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am undecided. This are two different things, although there are  very few  questions. I would let them separated for a while and see how things go.

Comment: I agree. See my comment on OP.

Comment: Accepted -- thanks to @BryanDenny for the insight!